# is_array() not working when reading JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sample JSON contents:

```
{"payment_records":{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}}
```

I had been using these codes for the past few days to read JSON file in PHP

```
$phpArray = json_decode($jsoncontents, false);
$retrievepayments = $phpArray->payment_records;
```

And recently I added a code to get each payments

```
foreach ($retrievepayments as $key1 => $value1)
     if (is_array($value1))
```

The code for `is_array` doesn't seem to work right. It kept going to false when it should be true, `$value1` do have array contents. If I'm wrong, what do I need to use to check? What I need is to check weather `$value1` only contain 1 array like `'{"Currency":"USD"}'` (perhaps 1 array is not called an array at all) or if `$value1` contains `'{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}'`.

EDIT:

I used phptester.net and palced the following scripts

```
$decodecontents = '{"Payment_History":{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}}';

$phpArray = json_decode($decodecontents, false);
$retrievepayments = $phpArray->Payment_History;

foreach ($retrievepayments as $key1 => $value1)
{
     #if (is_array($value1))
    if (is_object($value1))
     {
         echo "Hit!";
     }
    else
    {
        echo "NOT Hit!";
    }
}
```

and gotten

```
NOT Hit!Hit!
```

Hmm, I think it's telling me that `"Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}` is an object?

Comment: Have you tried to use `print_r($phpArray)` to actually see if it decodes alright? That said, `$value2` is never set, so obviously *nothing* is not an array and `false` is the correct answer.

Comment: I can print the `$value1` by doing `echo json_encode($value1);` so should I be using `if (is_array(json_encode($value1)))` instead?

Comment: Maybe you mean `$value1` not `$value2`?

Comment: @user3613603 Now you just need to post the results of `echo '<pre>' . print_r($phpArray, true) . '</pre>'` (edit your original post).

Comment: Can u show the whole json content.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't post the result of print as it contain sensitive information and it's too large to edit/cover the sensitive parts but when I `print_r($phpArray);` or `echo json_encode($value1);` they do display the array 1('{ blah blah }')1, the array is there and I can do more for loops to get each contents of the array, I just can't do a check to make sure the variable contain an array

Comment: Try to use is " is_object() " instead of " is_array " and see what comes out.

Comment: Without showing the content or a sample, it will be hard to get an answer.

Comment: @user3613603 You're getting your JSON from an API I suppose - can't you find an example somewhere else?

Comment: the JSON TXT file is downloaded from a website API. The content is for example `{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}` only the actual content is large. I use a file upload in html/php to get the contents

Comment: As @Mubo mentioned - your example does not contain any arrays, just a set of nested objects

Comment: @danneth sorry, but I thought `payment_records` contains 2 keys `Currency` and `Paid_Ammounts`? wherein `Paid_Ammounts` also contains further arrays

Comment: @danneth [Not true. JSON arrays are still arrays despite `$assoc` being false.](https://eval.in/149880)

Comment: @h2ooooooo JSON Arrays are denoted by [], not {}. `{"Paid_Ammounts": ["I am an array"]}` is not the same as `{"Paid_Ammounts": {"I am": "not an array"}}`

Comment: @danneth Ah yes, you're completely right. The last JSON you mentioned is invalid though, but the `Paid_Ammounts` are just an object with the keys `$json->{'Paid_Ammounts'}->{'1st Payment'}`.

Comment: yeah, I was a bit quick to make a point rather than actually thinking about typing valid JSON. Good catch though, you can never be too thorough

Comment: So how can I tell though if a $value contains further groups of information rather than just one plain $value?

Comment: @Mubo would you like to post your answer? It's weird to use is_object to check if a $value contains array (or whatever you call it) or not but is_object seem to do it so I'm picking it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Your solution is there, the following will loop through all entries in the `Paid_Ammounts`

```
$jsoncontents = '{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}';

$jsonObject = json_decode($jsoncontents, false);

foreach ($jsonObject->Paid_Ammounts as $key => $val)
{
        echo "{$key} --> {$val}\n";
}
```

Output of above will be

```
1st Payment --> 50
2nd Payment --> 75
3rd Payment --> 100
```

**UPDATE**
It's a bit unclear to me what you are actually trying to achieve, but you could do something like this to traverse the object

```
$jsoncontents = '{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}';

$jsonObject = json_decode($jsoncontents, false);

function printKeyVal($obj) 
{
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val)
    {
        if (is_object($val))
        {
            echo "{$key}\n";
            printKeyVal($val);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "{$key} --> {$val}\n";
        }
    }
}

printKeyVal($jsonObject);
```

Which will output

```
Currency --> USD
Paid_Ammounts
1st Payment --> 50
2nd Payment --> 75
3rd Payment --> 100
```

And should keep "digging" if the object is nested deeper

Comment: This is not the problem though, this works fine since the content of `Paid_Ammounts` is plain `"Key":"Value"`. What about for a value that has multiple keys and values in it. I mean if `$jsoncontents = '{"Payment_History":{"Currency":"USD","Paid_Ammounts":{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75","3rd Payment":"100"}}}';` and you wanted to do a `foreach ($jsonObject->Payment_History-> as $key => $val)`, this would result in an error and that is my problem.

Comment: I just wanted to do a `foreach` to get the many keys and values of Payment_History and print them, it can print the plain keys and values but gives error if the value contains other set of info (ones I thought I can call as array but as you and h2ooooooo discussed, is an object)

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is, but I've updated my answer to be be able to traverse more nested levels

Comment: let's just say I wanted to get each users monthly bills for example, and a user can have mortgage:$600, gas:$300, and insurance:$1000, just an example. I can easily print mortgage and food to a php page, but insurance contains other information in it like health:$150 and death:$200. I am getting errors displaying insurance because of just  the amount (value), it contains more stuff to breakdown

Comment: Did you try running through the extended object in the function I posted above? Also, it would be a lot easier if you could update your question with the complete object you are trying to process

Comment: After a couple of testings with is_object() and is_array(), I think I have a conclusion. I think it considers `{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75"}` as object and `[{"1st Payment":"50","2nd Payment":"75"}]` as array. My JSON file contains a lot of data enclosed in `{` and `}` but some groups are enclosed in `[{` and `}]` and those are being detected as arrays.